# proxy_pass requests only if the requested file exists

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to proxy_pass requests to an application server **only if** the requested file exists?

There is the `if (!-f $request_filename)` way, but it is strongly recommended against by the nginx documentation: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/